# How to filter CreateSet in a table?

Tags: specflow

I'm trying to create a test, that takes a table, parses the table to create subsets of the table, using `CreateSet` to use my existing types.

The problem I'm running into is that I would like to create different lists depending on the table values being passed.

For example:

```
then: there are values
name|otherinfo         |isApple|isOrange|isMango|
ex1 |someinfo,otherinfo|true   |false   |false  |
ex2 |someinfo,otherinfo|true   |true    |true   |
```

I want to use `CreateSet` to create a list of subset of the tables based on these flags.

Something like:

```cs
List<apples> apples = table.CreateSet<apples>(only get apples).ToList();
```

But every LINQ statement I have tried fails. How do I do the "only get apples" part here?

**Note: Also, the types I want to use do not have these identifier flags, these are just in the table.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't. The intellisense for the parameter where you put *only get apples* reveals that it is `Func<T> methodToCreateEachInstance`.

But that doesn't mean there isn't another way

```
Feature: SpecFlowFeature1
In order to help people on StackOverflow
As a helpful soul
I want to discover how to use CreateSet

Scenario: Retreive and filter a table
  Given I have some values:
      | name | otherinfo          | isApple | isOrange | isMango |
      | ex1  | someinfo,otherinfo | true    | false    | false   |
      | ex2  | someinfo,otherinfo | true    | true     | true    |
  Then MyApples should not be empty
```

And in your binding

```
//using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist;
using Should;

public class Example
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string otherInfo { get; set; }
}

[Binding]
public class StepBindings
{
    public IEnumerable<Example> MyApples { get; set; }

    [Given(@"I have some values:")]
    public void GivenIHaveSomeValues(Table table)
    {
        var onlyApples = table.Rows.Where(x => bool.Parse(x["isApple"]));

        MyApples = from x in onlyApples
                   select new Example
                   {
                       name = x["name"],
                       otherInfo = x["otherInfo"]
                   };
    }

    [Then(@"MyApples should not be empty")]
    public void ThenMyApplesShouldNotBeEmpty()
    {
        MyApples.ShouldNotBeNull();
        MyApples.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
    }

}
```